# Filtrar sobre un atributo de un Modelo en SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

expongo mi problema:

Tengo 2 tablas, **User** y **Order**, con la relación de un **User** puede tener 0 o Muchos (0:M) **Orders**.

El modelo de SQLAlchemy que tengo es el siguiente.

```py
class User(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'user'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = Column(String)
    orders = relationship("Order")

class Order(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'order'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    user_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('user.id'))
    created_at = Column(Date, default=datetime.datetime.now())
```

Cuando hago la búsqueda de un **User**, me permite hacer un `user1.orders` para sacar los **Order** de ese **User**.

Hasta aquí todo bien, pero lo que quiero ahora es obtener los **Users** que tengan un **Order** realizado el día actual.

```py
result = session.query(User).join(Order).filter(Order.created_at == datetime.datetime.now())
```

La consulta funciona bien y me devuelve todos los Users que han hecho un pedido el día actual, pero al volver a hacer `user1.orders` me devuelve todos los **Orders** aunque no sean del día de hoy. Y lo que yo quiero es al hacer `user1.orders` solo tenga los **Orders** del día de hoy. Cuando recorro la lista.

```py
for user in result:
   for order in user.orders:
      print (order.id, order.created_at)
```

Al hacer el `user.orders` se me devuelven todos los **Order** y no solos los de hoy sino todos.

Al hacer la consulta en SQL puro en la base de datos si obtengo lo que necesito, pero quiero aprovecharme de los beneficios de SQLAlchemy:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM user, order
WHERE user.id = order.user_id
AND order.created_at = CURRENT_DATE()
```

¿Como podría solo quedarme con los **Order** del día de hoy en la consulta?